# "He's too soft of a character to be our leader," seems to be grammatically correct. Or is it?

Tags: grammar

And if indeed it is syntactically correct, what's the plural form of the phrase if referring to two or more characters? "They are too soft of a character to be good candidates." —is this wrong?

Comment: Hi nicheese, welcome to writing.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Unfortunately this kind of grammar request is off-topic here, but is on-topic over at [english.se]. This question may get migrated, but if not you can post a version of it there. Please remember to review their posting guidelines before doing so though. Good luck and if you do have a writing specific question I encourage you to ask it here.

Comment: Get rid of the "of", so that it becomes "He's too soft a character to be our leader". As for the plural form, I would go with "They are of too soft a character to be good candidates."

Answer (score 2):

Garner, in *Modern American Usage* (p586) doesn't like *of* in such expressions:

> *Intrusive 'of'*: The word *of* often intrudes where it doesn't idiomatically belong, as in **not that big of a deal* (read *not that
>   big a deal*), **not too smart of a student* (read *not too smart a
>   student*)... .

*Merriam–Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (p680) typically takes a more nuanced approach, noting its frequent use in a variety of contexts. It concludes:

> The only sure thing is that when normative usage writers encounter
>   these idioms their reaction is to condemn. ... The only stricture on
>   it is that it is a spoken idiom; you will not want to use it much in
>   writing except of the personal kind.

Others here have suggested how the sentence could be formulated in the plural.

Comment: "... except of the personal kind" Nicely done, MW.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence in question, sounds like part of a dialogue.

So in the context of a spoken line, it is grammatically acceptable.

That said, it is a very clumsy and clunky sentence.

The "of" is superfluous.

But then again "of a character" is also superfluous, as character is already implied.  Very few would think soft to mean the man is soft and squishy like a pillow to be a leader.

Answer (score -1):

It's "He's too soft a character to be our leader". (The same sentence as Marcus Hendriksen suggested in a comment.)

For the plural, I'd go for "They're too soft characters to be our leaders". Presumably each person is being judged separately and found to be too soft, hence "characters".

Comment: This is a very black and white answer.